# Filter column value while using ALL_TAB_COLUMNS

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

In SQL Oracle, is there a way to filter an `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` `SELECT` statement, by the values in a specific column?

Answer (score 1):

Yes; you'll need PL/SQL with dynamic SQL to do that.

Here's an example I use to search through current user's tables, check the ones that contain `ENAME` column which contains `SCOTT` string within. The result says that two tables (`EMPLOYEE` and `EMP`) contain one row with such a value.

Adjust it to your needs.

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL> DECLARE
  2    l_str VARCHAR2(500);
  3    l_cnt NUMBER := 0;
  4  BEGIN
  5    FOR cur_r IN (SELECT u.table_name, u.column_name
  6                  FROM user_tab_columns u, user_tables t
  7                  WHERE u.table_name = t.table_name
  8                    AND u.column_name = 'ENAME'
  9                 )
 10    LOOP
 11      l_str := 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' || cur_r.table_name ||
 12              ' WHERE ' || cur_r.column_name || ' like (''%SCOTT%'')';
 13
 14      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (l_str) INTO l_cnt;
 15
 16      IF l_cnt > 0 THEN
 17        dbms_output.put_line(l_cnt ||' : ' || cur_r.table_name);
 18      END IF;
 19    END LOOP;
 20  END;
 21  /
1 : EMPLOYEE
1 : EMP

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```